# Setting up GUI with Ubuntu from Windows Store

Tags: gui, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've recently downloaded Ubuntu from the Windows Store (I'm running windows 10) and I wanted to start familiarize with it, I saw that it's possible not only to have the bash command line, but also a graphical interface. However, in the tutorial I saw (https://www.pcgamer.com/linux-in-windows-10/) it seems that the method to start up the GUI is outdated/not working properly, could someone help me setting the GUI up so I can start Ubuntu inside Windows and use it? Thank you.